# PyGTK TextView that only accepts single lines

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I feel rather silly to ask this, but how does one create a TextView that only accepts single lines? Most other gui toolkits have a method such as "setMultiline" etc, but PyGTK seems to really enjoy multiple lines. Some other languages have "TextFields" for these simpler text boxes.

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextview.html#method-gtktextview--set-justification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `gtk.Entry`?

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkentry.html

Comment: I found it a minute before you, but thanks for responding anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it. I suppose the name makes sense...

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkentry.html